# Personalizing fill colors on each facet in a barplot ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

I want to make a barplot in facets.

[image]

```
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)

mtcars0 = mtcars %>% group_by(cyl) %>% mutate(MeanMpg = round(mean(mpg), 2))

p <- ggplot(mtcars0, aes(mpg, wt)) + 
  geom_bar(stat = "identity", width = 2) + 
  facet_grid(~ cyl ~. ) + 
  geom_text(aes(mpg, wt, label = MeanMpg), size = 4, x = 15, y = 5)
```

the problem is when I try to personalize colorbars according to each facet (1 facet 1 color).

```
p <- ggplot(mtcars0, aes(mpg, wt, fill = cyl)) + 
  geom_bar(stat = "identity", width = 2) + 
  facet_grid(~ cyl ~. ) + 
  geom_text(aes(mpg, wt, label = MeanMpg), size = 4, x = 15, y = 5) +
  scale_fill_manual(values = c("royalblue", "orange", "orangered"))
p
```

How can I fill my bars?

Comment: You just need `fill = factor(cyl)` to make it discrete rather than continuous I think.

Comment: Add `check_overlap = TRUE` to your `geom_text` to make the text look better

Comment: `mpg` is a continuous variable. You might be looking for a histogram instead of a bar plot? Or use `cut()` to divide `mpg`'s values into discrete bins before passing the dataframe to `ggplot()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to fill bars with a column of `factor` class rather than `double` class. You can convert `cyl` column into factors with `as.factor()` function on the fly:

```
p <- ggplot(mtcars0, aes(mpg, wt, fill = as.factor(cyl))) + 
  geom_bar(stat = "identity", width = 2) + 
  facet_grid(~ cyl ~. ) + 
  geom_text(aes(mpg, wt, label = MeanMpg), size = 4, x = 15, y = 5) +
  scale_fill_manual(values = c("royalblue", "orange", "orangered"))
p
```

[image]